# nginx reverse-proxy for all subdomains except alredy defined

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a rather simple question, i have an enviroment, where i have often changing subdomains, but some are also presistent, now i want to forward api.example.com to `1.2.3.4:8080` and all other incoming requests to `2.3.4.5:9090`. My setup till now is that i forward all requests from the api subdomain points to `1.2.3.4:8080`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name api.example.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
  }
}
```

Now i need a way to point all other subdomains to `2.3.4.5:9090`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `default_server` in `listen`. See [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://2.3.4.5:9090;
    }
}
```

Comment: And even `server_name _;` can be omitted for the second server block :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to dynamically resolve your subdomains. the following config will take care of your situation.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    if ($subdomain = "api") {
                           proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
                    }

                    proxy_pass http://2.3.4.5:9090;
        }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, and looks efficient too.